# The requested module '@angular/compiler' does not provide an export named 'TypeModifier'. Am i missing anything while installing ng CLI?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

> npm i --save-dev @angular/compiler-cli

Using the above , i was able to install @angular/compiler-cli@13.1.3 Version.when i run,
**SyntaxError: The requested module '@angular/compiler' does not provide an export named 'TypeModifier'**
at ModuleJob._instantiate (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:104:21)
at async ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:149:5)
at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:177:24)How do i resolve such errors?

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? I suspect that you might want to do npm i -g @angular/cli ?

Comment: My target is to run ng serve. and i get "An unhandled exception occurred: The requested module '@angular/compiler' does not provide an export named 'TypeModifier'" . also i tried npm i -g @angular/cli  and the error persists.